# iCloud NSPredicate Error in iOS

Tags: ios, nspredicate, icloud

I am now searching document from iCloud in my iOS App with following codes

```
        NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[c] %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey,searchText];

        [self.notes filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
        [self.tblMainTableView reloadData];
```

When i run and search it , it is showing error with following error messages

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Note 0x1cd4ed10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key kMDItemFSName.'
```

How can i search it?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up a predicate that uses `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey`, which is the same as `kMDItemFSName`. Then you use this predicate to try to filter the `self.notes` array. What the error message is telling you is that (a) this array contains at least one instance of a class named `Note`, and that (b) the `Note` class (unsurprisingly) does not have an attribute named `kMDItemFSName`. This causes an exception.

If you want to filter `self.notes`, you need to use a predicate that uses only attributes that actually exist on the objects contained in the array. I don't know what those attributes are or what you're really trying to accomplish here, but predicates must use attributes that exist on the objects they're filtering.

Comment: sorry but `NSMetadataQuery` returns `NSMetadataItems` that contain the attribute `NSMetadataItemFSNameKey`. This is probably some iOS bug. One more.